# Is there a way to disable indentation for one specific org-mode src block at a time?

Tags: emacs, indentation, org-mode, spacemacs

I'm using most of the standard features of `org-mode` that come with the spacemacs develop branch, but I haven't been able to find a way to disable the automatic indentation for source code blocks on a case by case basis. I use tangle and I'm writing `Dockerfile`'s in the same file that I'm writing groovy code or javascript for example. The `Dockerfile`'s are the only ones I want not to be indented so I can get syntax highlighting. Here's what it looks like without the indentation:

[image: ![Unindented Dockerfile]

And here's what it looks like with the indentation that automatically happens if I edit the text:

[image: Indented Dockerfile]

The automatic indentation is fine for groovy for example, so I have no issue with the automatic indentation here. (in fact, if I still got the syntax highlighting for `Dockerfile`'s I probably wouldn't mind too much except the weird word wrapping not respecting the background face). Here's the example with groovy:

[image: Groovy Source]

As you can see, I tried a `:noindent` property I found in the [org-mode docs](https://orgmode.org/manual/Org-Indent-Mode.html) that's usually in a `#+STARTUP` directive. I also searched stack overflow, but I didn't find anything fruitful that didn't disable indenting for all source blocks or for the entire file.

Answer (score 1):

In my practice (I'm not sure it is a good practice or not, just share it to you):

- I setup `org-src-tab-acts-natively` to `true` for using the language’s major-mode indentation. In your case, it will format the src block with the formatting rules of `dockerfile-mode`.
- I created a new major-mode `plain-mode` for the content which should not be indented automatically. Personally, I use this mode for something like:

  - shell outputs
  - ASCII diagrams
  - ...

```
#+begin_src plain
this will not
  be 
    auto
        indented
#+end_src

Above src block will not be indented when you select them as region, and TAB on them.
```

**In this way, the src blocks will always behavior as expected when formatting them.**

---

Aside, the example code of plain-mode:

```lisp
(define-derived-mode plain-mode
  clean-mode "Plain"
  "Major mode for plain text."
  ;; preserve the auto indentation on line
  (setq-local indent-line-function 'indent-relative)
  ;; disable auto indentation on region
  (setq-local indent-region-function (lambda (start end))))
```